# Removal of NULL character in string in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have code in php which reads data from file but when I print original and unique words, the NULL character is included in them. So how could I remove them. I have also used trim and string replace functions but not fruitful. Following is the code for illustration.

```
$string = "A quick and the brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
$words = explode(" ",$string);
$unique = array_unique($words);

for ($a=0;$a<=count($unique);$a++) {
    if ($unique[$a] == NULL) {
        echo "NULL";
    }
    echo $unique[$a]." ";
}
echo "<br>";

for ($b=0;$b<=count($words);$b++) {
    if ($words[$b] == NULL) {
        echo "NULL";
    }
    echo $words[$b]." ";
}
```

This code is shown with a string and print a NULL character in each loop. But when I read a file then there are multiple NULL charactes in each loop. Please help me out. Thanks.

Comment: [Cannot Reproduce](http://codepad.viper-7.com/oZSdNn). should be `<` & not `<=` in your condition,`$b=0;$b<count($words);$b++`.

Comment: Use `foreach ($unique as $word)` instead of your `for` loop.

Comment: You would have gotten a hint by using `error_reporting(-1)` in your code to show all notices and warnings.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this

```
$unique = array_values(array_unique($words));
```

That is because `array_unique` preserves index and you will run into `Undefined Offset` notices.

Also, change your conditions on your `for` loop to `<` instead of `<=`

#### The modified code..

```
<?php

$string = "A quick and the brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
$words = explode(" ",$string);
$unique = array_values(array_unique($words)); //<--- You really need to do this !

for ($a=0;$a<count($unique);$a++) { //<--- Changed the operator
    if ($unique[$a] == NULL) {
        echo "NULL";
    }
    echo $unique[$a]." ";
}
echo "<br>";

for ($b=0;$b<count($words);$b++) { //<--- Changed the operator
    if ($words[$b] == NULL) {
        echo "NULL";
    }
    echo $words[$b]." ";
}
```

#### Using a `foreach` -> Proposed by [Jack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1338292/jack)

```
<?php

$string = "A quick and the brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
$words = explode(" ",$string);
$unique = array_unique($words);

foreach($unique as $k=>$v) {
    if ($unique[$k] == NULL) {
        echo "NULL";
    }
    echo $unique[$k]." ";
}
echo "<br>";

foreach ($words as $k=>$v) {
    if ($words[$k] == NULL) {
        echo "NULL";
    }
    echo $words[$k]." ";
}
```

Comment: Using `foreach()` would eliminate the need to use `array_values()`; also, you didn't really explain why this would be necessary :)

Comment: @Jack, I agree with that !! :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't you just want `str_replace("\0","null",$string)` or even `str_replace("\0","",$string)` ?